# phpMyAdmin - Status - Monitor - A fatal JavaScript error has occurred

Tags: javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin, monitor

When I open phpMyAdmin - Status - Monitor I get an error: A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?

Report message is:

```
{
"exception": {
    "mode": "stack",
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "chartObj is undefined",
    "stack": [
        {
            "func": "addChart",
            "args": "",
            "line": 1042,
            "column": "30",
            "context": [
                "    /* Adds a chart to the chart grid */",
                "    function addChart(chartObj, initialize) {",
                "",
                "        var i;",
                "        var settings = {",
                "            title: escapeHtml(chartObj.title),",
                "            grid: {",
                "                drawBorder: false,",
                "                shadow: false,",
                "                background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'",
                "            },"
            ],
            "filename": "server_status_monitor.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "initGrid",
            "args": "",
            "line": 991,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "        $.each(runtime.charts, function (key, value) {",
                "            keys.push(key);",
                "        });",
                "        keys.sort();",
                "        for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {",
                "            addChart(runtime.charts[keys[i]], true);",
                "        }",
                "",
                "        /* Fill in missing cells */",
                "        var numCharts = $('#chartGrid .monitorChart').length;",
                "        var numMissingCells = (monitorSettings.columns - numCharts % monito//..."
            ],
            "filename": "server_status_monitor.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "?",
            "args": "",
            "line": 667,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "        if (! runtime.redrawCharts) {",
                "            $(this).html(PMA_getImage('play.png') + ' ' + PMA_messages.strR//...",
                "        } else {",
                "            $(this).html(PMA_getImage('pause.png') + ' ' + PMA_messages.str//...",
                "            if (! runtime.charts) {",
                "                initGrid();",
                "                $('a[href=\"#settingsPopup\"]').show();",
                "            }",
                "        }",
                "        return false;",
                "    });"
            ],
            "filename": "server_status_monitor.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "ErrorReport.wrap_function/new_func",
            "args": "",
            "line": 249,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "     */",
                "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                "            var new_func = function () {",
                "                try {",
                "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                "                } catch (x) {",
                "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                "                }",
                "            };",
                "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
            ],
            "filename": "error_report.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.event.dispatch",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "$event.dispatch",
            "args": "",
            "line": 374,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                "\t\treturn;",
                "\t}",
                "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                "};",
                "",
                "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                "var touchHooks = ",
                "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.event.add/u",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.event.trigger",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": ".trigger/<",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": ".each",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.prototype.each",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": ".trigger",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "?",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2090,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "    }",
                "});",
                "",
                "// Run the monitor once loaded",
                "AJAX.registerOnload('server_status_monitor.js', function () {",
                "    $('a[href=\"#pauseCharts\"]').trigger('click');",
                "});",
                "",
                "function serverResponseError() {",
                "    var btns = {};",
                "    btns[PMA_messages.strReloadPage] = function () {"
            ],
            "filename": "server_status_monitor.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "ErrorReport.wrap_function/new_func",
            "args": "",
            "line": 249,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "     */",
                "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                "            var new_func = function () {",
                "                try {",
                "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                "                } catch (x) {",
                "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                "                }",
                "            };",
                "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
            ],
            "filename": "error_report.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.event.dispatch",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "$event.dispatch",
            "args": "",
            "line": 374,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                "\t\treturn;",
                "\t}",
                "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                "};",
                "",
                "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                "var touchHooks = ",
                "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.event.add/u",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.event.trigger",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": ".trigger/<",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": ".each",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "v.prototype.each",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": ".trigger",
            "args": "",
            "line": 2,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */\r",
                "(function(e,t){function _(e){var t=M[e]={};return v.each(e.split(y),functio//...",
                "",
                "/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */",
                "/**",
                " * This object handles ajax requests for pages. It also",
                " * handles the reloading of the main menu and scripts."
            ],
            "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "AJAX.fireOnload",
            "args": "",
            "line": 105,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "     *",
                "     * @return void",
                "     */",
                "    fireOnload: function (file) {",
                "        var eventName = 'onload_' + AJAX.hash(file);",
                "        $(document).trigger(eventName);",
                "        if (this._debug) {",
                "            console.log(",
                "                // no need to translate",
                "                \"Fired event \" + eventName + \" for file \" + file",
                "            );"
            ],
            "filename": "ajax.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "AJAX.scriptHandler.done",
            "args": "",
            "line": 430,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "        done: function () {",
                "            if (typeof ErrorReport !== 'undefined') {",
                "                ErrorReport.wrap_global_functions();",
                "            }",
                "            for (var i in this._scriptsToBeFired) {",
                "                AJAX.fireOnload(this._scriptsToBeFired[i]);",
                "            }",
                "            AJAX.active = false;",
                "        },",
                "        /**",
                "         * Appends a script element to the head to load the scripts"
            ],
            "filename": "ajax.js"
        },
        {
            "func": "?",
            "args": "",
            "line": null,
            "column": "",
            "context": [
                "        }",
                "    });",
                "});",
                ";",
                "",
                "AJAX.scriptHandler.done();"
            ],
            "filename": "server_status_sorter.js"
        }
    ],
    "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0",
    "uri": "server_status_monitor.php?target="
},
"script_name": "server_status_monitor.php",
"pma_version": "4.1.12",
"browser_name": "FIREFOX",
"browser_version": "28.0",
"user_os": "Win",
"server_software": "Apache",
"user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0",
"locale": "en",
"configuration_storage": "enabled",
"php_version": "5.4.27",
"microhistory": {
    "pages": [
        {
            "hash": "index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=032efd2ec46abfaaf1ff3bbb7c2a9f0d"
        },
        {
            "hash": "server_status.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=032efd2ec46abfaaf1ff3bbb7c2a9f0d",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "querywindow_height": "400",
                "querywindow_width": "600",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "confirm": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "hash": "server_status_monitor.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=032efd2ec46abfaaf1ff3bbb7c2a9f0d",
            "params": {
                "opendb_url": "db_structure.php",
                "safari_browser": "0",
                "querywindow_height": "400",
                "querywindow_width": "600",
                "collation_connection": "utf8mb4_general_ci",
                "lang": "en",
                "server": "1",
                "text_dir": "ltr",
                "pma_text_default_tab": "Browse",
                "pma_text_left_default_tab": "Structure",
                "confirm": "true"
            }
        }
    ],
    "current_index": "3"
}
```

}

I try in IE, FireFox and Chrome.
Can anybody help to fix it?

Comment: chartObj is undefined. what is chartObj supposed to be?

Comment: Here are code with chartObj http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=itSdCgLFPMFdd3flNfav8jlDko0&cid=uXtUw5YhiiU&s=&fp=305271&mp&projSelected=true#L0

Comment: What Version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: Solution1:Update your browsers java version,Solution2:open your localhost/phpmyadmin in a different browser and see if it gives you an error,if it doesnt,then it means the fresh browser you opened your localhost in has the lastest java version.No need for all that chartObj junk...waste of time